# Why does "Animate on Event" (without a listener) work in A-Frame 0.6.1, but not 0.9.0? Is this a bug?

Tags: aframe

The code provided here does not work in A-Frame 0.9.0, but works perfectly in 0.6.1:

https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/guides/building-a-basic-scene.html#animating-on-events

Infact, the linked example (which works) uses 0.6.1, even though the documentation is for 0.9.0:

https://aframe-basic-guide-with-environment.glitch.me/

I took that exact same source and tried it with 0.9.0, the scene loads, but there are no mouseenter/mouseleave effects.

Does 0.9.0 require something else? Has this feature been removed? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a-animation was removed for animation https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/animation.html. I will update that guide now. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the guide. https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/guides/building-a-basic-scene.html